# Why do we do "INT_MAX/10" and not just INT_MAX?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14

I was solving an easy question to reverse a 32-bit signed integer but I can't understand one part. To handle the overflow I tried applying `if(res > INT_MAX || res< INT_MIN)` and `if(res*10 > INT_MAX || res*10< INT_MIN)` but none of them worked. Only `if(res > INT_MAX/10 || res< INT_MIN/10)` worked. I couldn't understand the reason.

```
int reverse(int x) {
   int rem,res=0;
    while(x!=0)
    {
        rem=x%10;
        x=x/10;
        if((res  > INT_MAX/10) || (res  < INT_MIN/10)){
            return 0;
        }
        res=(res*10)+rem;

    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Think about what `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` are.  Can you have an `int` that is more than `INT_MAX` or less than `INT_MIN`?

Comment: Because `res=(res*10)+rem;` will otherwise overflow and it seems that you are lucky because the `+rem` still has a decent chance to overflow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some_int_expression > INT_MAX` and `some_int_expression < INT_MIN` are never useful because those are always false. No int value can be larger than `INT_MAX` and no int value can be less than `INT_MIN`.

When `res  > INT_MAX/10` is true, doing `res * 10` will cause the operation to overflow the representable range of `int`, and as a consequence, the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to guarantee `res=(res*10)+rem;` is not causing overflow. You know that `res <= INT_MAX`, since `INT_MAX` is the *highest* `int` value. So for `(res*10)+rem;` not to overflow, you need to make sure `(res*10)+rem <= INT_MAX` <=> `res <= (INT_MAX - rem)/10`. Negating, we should thus abort if `res > (INT_MAX - rem)/10`

Similar logic applied for `INT_MIN`: `res < (INT_MIN - rem)/10`

Checking `res > INT_MAX/10` and `res < INT_MIN/10` instead was enough, since you were lucky enough they had no test cases for the full case.